# xrandr reports external VGA output connected even with no cable attached

Tags: xorg, 9.10

I have a machine running Karmic which is embedded in a large screen. When I run `xrandr -q`, it reports that the VGA output is connected, even when there is no screen attached. This is causing some issues with other resolution-related software (that I can't change at the moment).

Is there a way to disable the VGA output so that it doesn't show up at all, or is there some fix I can backport so that it no longer reports incorrectly? Some info on the system is below. As far as I can tell it happens only on this hardware.

### xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 864, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768       59.8* 
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        59.9  
LVDS connected 1152x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1680x1050      84.9     74.9     69.9     60.0  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      85.0     74.8     70.0     60.0  
   1280x1024      85.0     75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       85.0     60.0  
   1360x768       59.8  
   1152x864      100.0     85.1     85.0     75.0     75.0     70.0     60.0* 
   1024x768       85.0     75.0     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        85.1     72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        85.0     72.8     75.0     59.9  
   720x400        85.0  
   640x400        85.1  
   640x350        85.1  
TV disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

### lspci

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 8030
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 27
    Region 0: Memory at fe900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at c000 [size=8]
    Capabilities: [90] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable+
        Address: fee0100c  Data: 4191
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Bridge: PM- B3+
    Kernel modules: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 8030
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Bridge: PM- B3+
```

Comment: Please file a bug about this.  `ubuntu-bug -s display`

Comment: Right; it looks like your device needs a quirk. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks for more information.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After adding

```
Option "monitor-VGA" "VGA"
```

to the "Device" section of your xorg.conf, add the following "Monitor" section:

```
Section "Monitor" 
    Identifier "VGA" 
    Option "Ignore" "True" 
EndSection
```

This will tell X to ignore the output.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know

Comment: So, did it work for you?